# Pass SearchView Query From Starting Fragment to Another Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, searchview

in my Fragment class I have this:

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu)
        val searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
        searchView = searchItem.actionView as SearchView
        searchView.apply{
            queryHint = "Search"
            isIconified = false
            setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{
                override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String): Boolean {
                    // pass the query to the other fragment and navigate to it
                    findNavController().navigate(GroupListFragmentDirections.actionGroupListFragmentToSearchedGroupListFragment(query))
                    return false
                }

                override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String): Boolean {
                    // start the search
                    //groupListViewModel.searchGroups(newText)
                    return false
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

Now, what happens is that I want to pass the query to the other fragment and navigate to it. The other fragment then processes the query in a certain way. 
But Android Studio tells me that SearchView has no NavController set.
Here the error message I found in the LogCat:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: View androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView{c83b4ef VFE...... ........ 147,10-987,136 #7f08003d app:id/action_search} does not have a NavController set
        at androidx.navigation.Navigation.findNavController(Navigation.java:84)
        at androidx.navigation.ViewKt.findNavController(View.kt:28)
        at com.celik.abdullah.mylim4.ui.GroupListFragment$onCreateOptionsMenu$1$1.onQueryTextSubmit(GroupListFragment.kt:93)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView.onSubmitQuery(SearchView.java:1191)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView$7.onEditorAction(SearchView.java:1168)
        at android.widget.TextView.onEditorAction(TextView.java:5911)
        at com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection.performEditorAction(EditableInputConnection.java:138)
        at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:360)
        at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:85)
...
```

I use the NavigationUI library from the Android Architecture Components. The MainActivity's layout contains the NavHostFragment layout widget. The fragment code you have seen above is the starting fragment(the fragment that the user sees when the app opens).

I assume that is not allowed to use the findNavController() within the listener for the searchview.
Nevertheless, is there a wordaround to pass a query from the searchview to the next fragment.

here is my activity layout:

```
// activity_main.xml
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/myNavHostFragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and here my navigation.xml:

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/groupListFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/groupListFragment"
        android:name="com.celik.abdullah.mylim4.ui.GroupListFragment"
        android:label="GroupListFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_group_list">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_groupListFragment_to_searchedGroupListFragment"
            app:destination="@id/searchedGroupListFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/searchedGroupListFragment"
        android:name="com.celik.abdullah.mylim4.ui.SearchedGroupListFragment"
        android:label="SearchedGroupListFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_searched_group_list">
        <argument
            android:name="query"
            app:argType="string" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

Comment: Can you post your navigation xml and your activity xml that contains the navigation?

Comment: @Christilyn: I have added them.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `SearchView` in your `Toolbar`, you should set up your `Toolbar` with your navigation:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    ...

    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph)
    findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar)
        .setupWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
}
```

Similarly for `ActionBar`:

```
setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
```

See this link for more details: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#appbarconfiguration